# Ingress creates location / (root path match all) in nginx config on specific servername, avoiding path to be found on default servername

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am running into this problem (or behave) of Ingress I can't understand:
If I have a path: /api1 configed in ingess without a specified host name, like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api1
  namespace: somenamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api1
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: service-for-api1
              servicePort: 1234
```

Then I can access this path in any hostname or IP address as long as it points to my server, e.g.  my-server.com/api1 or 1.2.3.4/api1

And If I added another ingress config with a specified host name, like: /api2

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api2
  namespace: somenamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-server.com   # Only difference is this one has a host field
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api2
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: service-for-api2
              servicePort: 1234
```

Then I can access my-server.com/api2 all right, But when accessing my-server.com/api1, I got a 404 not found error. If try to access through IP, 1.2.3.4/api1, It works all right.

I read the nginx config generated by ingress, found out when no host is specified in ingress config, the path rule (/api1) will be added to servername _ which is the default server of nginx. And once a hostname is provided in ingress config, It (/api2) will be added to servername hostname block in nginx configfile. Also there will be a location / rule to match all path in this hostname, preventing all paths fallback to default server. So when access my-server.com/api2, the route is okey but when access my-server.com/api1, It matches location / in servername my-server.com block, preventing default server functioning at all.

Why do ingress do this??

I was believing not specify any hostname in ingress config means host: *, thus any host can match the rule. But it behaves like only hostname unknown to ingress can match host: *.

The nginx config I looked at is like this (forgive my for only copying part of it):

```
## start server _   
server {        
  server_name _ ;

  listen 80 default_server reuseport backlog=65535 ;        
  listen [::]:80 default_server reuseport backlog=65535 ;       
  listen 443 default_server reuseport backlog=65535 ssl http2 ;     
  listen [::]:443 default_server reuseport backlog=65535 ssl http2 ;                

  set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

  ...

  location /api1 {
  ...
  }
  ...
}
## end server _

## start server my-server.com
server {
  server_name my-server.com
 
  listen 80  ;
  listen [::]:80  ;
  listen 443  ssl http2 ;
  listen [::]:443  ssl http2 ;
  
  set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

  location /api2 {
  ....
  }

  location / {
    set $namespace      "somenamespace";
    set $ingress_name   "service-for-api2";
    set $service_name   "";
    set $service_port   "";
    set $location_path  "/";
    set $global_rate_limit_exceeding n;
    
    ...
    
    # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error

    proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout;
    proxy_next_upstream_timeout             0;
    proxy_next_upstream_tries               3;
    
    ...
  }
}
## end server my-server.com
```

When copying I noticed the "try the next upstream server before returning an error", Is it not work properly so I got a 404 instead of actually trying servername _ ? When I looked the nginx log, it said the 404 request is sent to service [upstream-default-backend], I don't know what it means.

After I discover this problem I deleted the specified hostname in /api2 and it work allright. But I jsut can't help wondering why ingress does this behave...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you running into with `Ingress` is actually expected and it's by design.

This would happen when you define an `Ingress` rule without specifying a host field. And when you add an new Ingress rule with a specified host field, that rule would become the default rule for incoming requests to that specific hostname, and the default server block will no longer use for requests to that hostname, requests to that hostname will handle by the server block with the matching `server_name` instead.

In your case, the server block for `my-server.com` includes a specific location block for `/api2`, but it is missing the location block for `/api1`. That's why when you try to access `my-server.com/api1`, `Nginx` couldn't find a matching location block and return 404.

You can fix this by either adding a location block for `/api1` in the server block for `my-server.com`, or remove the host field from the `Ingress` rule for `/api2` to make it the default rule again.